# accessing fields in a view template

Tags: views

I have a view that I want to create a view template for in my theme.

So, I have created: `views-view--homepage-suppliers.tpl.php`

I have then several content items of content type: `Supplier` that the view uses.

The have various fileds, such as `title`, `field_supplier_image`

How do i then access these fields in this view template?

Is it something along the lines of:

`$rows['field_supplier_image']`?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It would appear your using a 'Display output' template when you probably want a 'Row style' output so you can access fields. You will need to change your tempate by going to 'advanced > theme information', it will probably be something similar to 'views-view-fields--homepage-suppliers.tpl.php'.

You can then get a nid from the field and access a whole host of information through the node object.

```
  $nid = $row->{$view->field['field_supplier_image']->field_alias}; 
  $node = node_load($nid);
```

If you var_dump() the $node variable you can see what you have to play with.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after!!

Comment: Any chance of ticking this as answered then? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this in a field template:

```
$row->field_field_link_text[0]["rendered"]["#markup"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access fields through the $view->result object.

Here's an example I use to create a ical calendar:

(views-view--ical.tpl.php)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
<?php       
define('CRLF',"\r\n");
global $base_url;
$ical_time_format='Ymd\THis\Z';

function ical_extract_value($field,$key='value'){
    return $field['und'][0][$key];
}

function ical_shorten_line($line){
    $line=str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),'\n',$line);
    return trim(chunk_split($line,76,"\r\n "));
}

print 'PRODID:'.$base_url.'/'.current_path().CRLF;

foreach ($view->result as $node){
        $data=$node->_field_data['nid']['entity'];
//      print_r($data); // uncomment to see available data
        print 'BEGIN:VEVENT'.CRLF;
        print 'UID:'.$data->nid.'@'.$base_url.CRLF;
        $description = ical_extract_value($data->body);
        print ical_shorten_line('DESCRIPTION:'.$description).CRLF;
        print 'DTSTART:'.date($ical_time_format,ical_extract_value($data->field_start)).CRLF;
        print 'DTEND:'.date($ical_time_format,ical_extract_value($data->field_start,'value2')).CRLF;
        /** other fields here **/
        $keywords = ical_extract_value($data->field_tag_list);
        $keywords = str_replace(' ', ',',$keywords);
        print ical_shorten_line('CATEGORIES:'.$keywords).CRLF;
        print 'END:VEVENT'.CRLF;
} ?>
END:VCALENDAR
```

As you can see, a certain field value can be accessed by $view->result[n]->filed_xxx['und'][0]['value'].